# Хранить картинки в базе данных или в файловой системе?

Tags: postgresql

Картинки нужно создавать, удалять, но чаще всего считывать. Подскажите где выше производительность будет: в первом или втором случае?

**Update**

---

если учесть те факт что бд это один файл и жёсткий диск подвергается своевременной дефрагментации, то можно говорить что данные будут считываться с одного места на диске, а если их хранить (тоже допустим в дефрагментированной) файловой системе, то всё равно велика вероятность что файлы будут разбросаны как попало. Таким образом на операцию чтения будет затрачиваться дополнительное время нужное для перемещения магнитной головки. Меня интересует именно эта проблема. Или я не прав?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кроме всего вышесказанного, во-первых, я не считаю, что фрагментацией базы можно пренебречь, ведь далеко не все дефрагментаторы позволяют дефрагментировать один файл большого размера.. Ведь если впихнуть пару гигабайт картинок в базу, фрагментация заметно отразится на скорости чтения файлов из базы. Во-вторых, повреждение одной лишь базы ведёт к потере всех картинок, чем не так чревата файловая система. И в-третьих, Вы уверены, что вам не понадобится в будущем передать пару картинок по сети?..

Comment: Современные СУБД способны частично восстанавливать данные из поврежденных файлов БД.
А вот с передачей по сети согласен, без дополнительных средств не обойтись. Например, при такой реализации, связка Apache + Nginx уже не будет столь эффективна.

Answer (score 1):

Смотря на то, как Вы собираетесь их использовать, и как реализована база. Учитывая, что скорость чтения из файла базы данных меньше, чем из файловой системы, нежелательно обрабатывать несколько картинок в базе. Хотя, с точки зрения защиты, база желательнее.

Comment: на чём основано ваше суждение, что скорость чтения из БД ниже чем из файловой системы? Мне нужны факты

Comment: На том, что база данных - это такой же файл. Который при работе с ней ещё обрабатывается сервисом.

Comment: В качестве примера того, что файловая система быстрее базы данных, можно привести архив, пусть с нулевым сжатием, или наш любимый Virtual Box, который все данные хранит в одном файле. И таких примеров можно привести много. Просто в файловой системе обрабатывается нужный файл, а в базе -- именно файл базы, а, значит, и не нужные в данный момент файлы.

Answer (score 1):

Один ответ уже Вам дали - по причине того, что доступ к файлам БД осуществляется через сервис, скорость доступа будет меньше, чем прямой доступ.

Теперь дальше, давайте представим, что все же у вас много ОЗУ и ваша БД со всеми картинками может быть закеширована. А теперь подумайте, сколько реально у вас ОЗУ (может быть выделено на сервис БД), как часто происходит обращение к одним и тем же изображениям, а как часто к новым (которых нету в кэше). И взвесьте все это с тем временем, которое необходимо, чтобы что-то из кэш удалить и новое поместить. Когда это несколько картинок статических, то почему бы и нет, а когда это база, обновляемая, корректируемая и т.п. Тогда при отсутствии ресурсов это глупо. Не говоря уже о том, а что будет СУБД делать в то время, когда отдает файл, если он большой или добавляет новый? При записи нового файла будет простой, так как таблица будет заблокирована, например.

Answer (score 0):

Дада, храните всё в БД, и картинки и скрипты ... и код выполняйте из базы.
Я бы сам залез в базу и каждый день бекапился.

А если серьёзно, то конечно же нужно использовать файловую систему!

Comment: тогда обоснуйте почему, и гугл и яндекс хранят кэшированные тайлы карт в sqlite. Я имею ввиду приложение для iPhone Google Maps и Яндекс.Карты

Comment: А как вы думаете, сколько нужно места, чтобы закэшировать эти карты? Минимум! Параллельного обращения к ним не будет, параллельное чтение-запись тоже отпадает в общем-то. Многое зависит от реализации, как вам уже писали ранее.